# What phrases to use for certain situations when your little children play in the playground?

Tags: phrase-request

I have sometimes a hard time when I take my children to the playground and something happens, like my child pushed another one or gets a bite from another one. I manage to say something most of the time but I am never sure that I said it in a proper way.

Here are some example situations where I am not sure what to say.

1. [To encourage a child](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/7394/23)
2. [What to say to other children](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/7395/23)
3. [To discipline my children](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/7392/23)
4. [To stop children from doing something dangerous](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/7396/23)

If possible, I would like this question to become a community-wiki type and I would like to know in what situations what you will say commonly. I started with the list I have. I collected the phrases and sentences by googling and listening to other parents who may or may not speak good German.

Please add other phrases or other situations.

Comment: Turning a question 180° isn't a nice thing to do.

Comment: @userunknown: the question needed a 180° turn to survive.

Comment: Reworded question and made a table of content for better readability. Feel free to further split or add other situations, above is just a framework from what we have. If somebody feels like having spare time we may also think of adding English translations to the answers.

Answer (score 6):

### To discipline my children

> - Sei vorsichtig! Halt dich fest! Mach dich nicht schmutzig! (Be careful! / / Don’t get dirty!)

- Pass auf, sonst fällst du! (Watch out, otherwise you will fall down!)
- Das kannst du nicht! (You cannot do that! / You are not able to do that!)
- Komm da sofort runter! (Come down immediately!)
- Komm, ich helfe dir! (Come on, I will help you!)
- Ja, richtig. Nein, das ist falsch. (Yes, you are right. No, that is wrong.)
- Gib mir bitte die Butter rüber. (Pass me the butter please.)
- Schätzchen, lass das bitte! (Sweetie, please don’t do that!)
- Sei bitte leise, damit ich telefonieren kann. (Please be quiet, so that I can make a telephone call.)
- Ich trage dich zwei Stufen hoch, dann gehst du drei Stufen selber, dann trage ich dich wieder usw. (I lift you two stages, then you will walk three stages yourself, then I will lift you etc.)
- Jeder braucht mal eine Pause, aber morgen gehst du wieder hin, abgemacht?! (Everyone needs a break, but tomorrow you will go there again, all right?!)
- Du hast nun genug. (That’s enough now.)
- Versuch es mit tauschen, du fändest es doch auch nicht toll, wenn ich dir das einfach wegnehmen würde. (Try it with swapping; you wouldn’t like it either, if I’d simply take that away.)
- Erinnere dich an die Regel, die wir abgesprochen haben. (Remember the rule we agreed on.)
- Lieb sein! (Be nice!)
- Beeil dich! (Hurry up!)
- Manchmal hören andere nicht richtig zu. (Sometimes others don’t listen carefully.)
- Hey, das war nicht okay, was du gerade getan hast. (Hey, that wasn’t okay what you just did!)
- redet ordentlich mit mir. (Talk nice to me.)
- ihr werdet ein paar Minuten warten. (You will wait some minutes.)
- Ei machen, das ist viel schöner. (Stroke/pet gently, that is much nicer.)
- Warum weint xxx? Wer hat es zuerst gehabt? Hast du gefragt? (Why does xxx cry? Who had it first? Did you ask?)
- Du bist dran. (It’s your turn.)
- Ihr müsst euch anstellen und der Reihe nach mit der Rutsche spielen. (You have to queue up for playing with the slide.)
- Nicht streiten, seid nett zueinander! (Don’t argue, be nice to each other!)
- Passt bitte auf die Jüngeren auf und rennt nicht so schnell. (Please pay attention to the younger ones and don’t run so fast.)
- Pass auf, die Kleine! Sei langsam und vorsichtig bitte. (Attention, little one! Be slow and careful, please.)
- Aufpassen, das ist noch ein ganz Kleiner! (Be careful, that one is really young!)
- Sei nett bitte, wir hauen nicht, wir schubsen nicht. (Please be nice, we don’t beat each other, we don’t push each other.)
- Nicht auf dem Mund küssen bitte. (Don’t kiss on the mouth.)
- Bitte langsamer. (Slower, please.)
- Mary, lass mal bitte die Dame vorbei. (Mary, please let the lady pass.)
- Was du nicht willst, was man dir tu, das füg auch keinem andern zu. (Don’t handle others in a way you wouldn’t want to be handled.)
- Die Rutsche gehört hier allen Kindern. Rutsch jetzt runter, hier stehen auch noch andere Kinder, die mal rutschen wollen. (The slide belongs to everyone here. Slide down, there are other kids waiting.)
- Lass das bitte sein! (Stop that, please!)
- Was ist genau passiert? (What happened exactly?)
- Das tut doch weh./Du tust ihm weh. (But that hurts! You hurt him.)
- Schau, das Kind weint jetzt – so weh hast du ihm getan! (See, the kid cries now – you hurt him so much.)
- Wenn du immer wieder andere Kinder beißt/trittst/schlägst, kannst du nicht mehr mit ihnen spielen. Deswegen gehen wir jetzt heim. (If you bite/kick/beat other kids again and again, you cannot play with them. That’s why we’re going home now.)
- Wir gehen jetzt und nehmen unser Spielzeug mit. (We’re leaving now, and take the toys with us.)
- Das Spielzeug ist von ** und er muss jetzt nach Hause. Wenn er wiederkommt, bringt er sein Spielzeug wieder mit, dann kann man gemeinsam damit spielen. (This is **’s toy and he has to go home now. If he comes back, he will bring is toy again, then you can play together.)
- Hauen geht gar nicht, das ist klar. (Beating each other up is absolutely not acceptable.)

Comment: For the beginning learner, these untranslated examples are not worth much.

Comment: @indoxica: it's Community Wiki. Everybody is welcome to add some translations.

Comment: I added translations for every sentence, except the 2nd in the first row. I'd like to add, that some of the german sentences are typed uncarefully and in a informal way, so pay attention to that!

Comment: "Ei machen, das ist viel schöner.   (To make eggs, that is much nicer.)" -> What is this supposed to be? "To make eggs"? Nonsens. [Ei, ei machen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ei)? Perhaps, though you don't say this when you *discipline* your children.

Comment: @Em1, I changed the translation. It often happens that the child pet another child hard, at those times I need to tell the child instead of petting hard we should stroke gently.

Comment: Thanks Em1 I did not get it either but forgot to ask and ended up translating it literally. Pretty funny translation, now that I think of it. I simply was not familiar with the "ei machen" idiom, being a native German.

Answer (score 2):

1. What to say in this situation is more a question for https://parenting.stackexchange.com/
2. The phrase you're using is ambiguous - of course it is possible to "be impolite". "Das geht nicht" means that something is not possible. What you want to express would probably be rather something like

   > "Das ist nicht in Ordnung, so darfst Du Dich nicht benehmen / das darfst Du nicht tun!".

Hope that helps, even though I still have to more train my skills on the "Spielplatz".

Comment: I thought about asking a similar question on Parenting, but actually I know what to say but not in German. And I now get that "Das geht nicht" is not the right phrase to use when I try to stop a child from what he's doing.

Comment: Feel free to add this somewhere to the existing lists, or create another situations for the TOC :)

Answer (score 2):

### To encourage a child

> - Na los, trau dich! Das schaffst du! Das hast du toll gemacht!
> - Das kannst du schon.
> - Versuch's mal. Gut, dass du es versucht hast.
> - Beim nächsten Mal wirst Du es schon schaffen.
> - Was meinst du? Könnte das funktionieren? Sollen wir das mal ausprobieren?
> - Ich bin sehr zufrieden mit dir.

Answer (score 2):

### What to say to other children

> - Sofort aufhören!
> - Halt!
> - Darf ich mal bitte durch(vorbei)? Ich möchte durch!
> - Pass auf!
> - Nicht hauen./Du sollst mich nicht hauen!
> - Sei vorsichtig!
> - Lass das sein.
> - Du tust ihm/mir weh./Aua, das hat wehgetan!
> - Jetzt bist du an der Reihe. Ich bin dran. Du bist dran. (Erklärt den Kindern, dass sie gleich drankommen.)
> - Ich will mit dir spielen! Ich spiele mit.
> - Gib mir bitte ….
> - Lassen Sie mich in Ruhe! Lass mich in Ruhe!
> - In Ordnung/Einverstanden. (OK/Agreed.)
> - Hier, bitte. (Here you are.)
> - Jule hat mich ausgelacht.
> - Lass mich in Ruhe!
> - Mika hat mich geschubst! Immer wieder!

Answer (score 2):

### To stop children from doing something dangerous

> - Stop! *(this will immediately be understood and mostly works)*

Comment: Sometimes when "Stop" does not work, I will ask "Wo sind deine Eltern?"

Comment: yeah - shouting **"Stop!"** is meant for situations like e.g. when kids start running on the street without looking.

Comment: You are right. I was talking about not so emergency situations where I have asked the child to stop doing something but he did not listen and what he is doing will hurt himself or other children.